# Como realizar um SELECT DISTINCT - H2

Tags: select

Preciso realizar um `SELECT DISTINCT`no banco de dados `H2` porém do modo que estou fazendo não esta me retornando nada:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT lote
FROM LotesEncerrados l 
ORDER BY l.lote ASC
```

Fiz do mesmo modo no `PostgreSQL`e funcionou normalmente. Como poderia fazer no `H2`?

Comment: Pela [documentação](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select) esse uso padrão da sintaxe parece estar correto, o H2 não parece precisar de nada diferente... Pergunta besta de minha parte, mas a tabela não está vazia, está? Hahah...

Comment: @nunks.lol Não a tabela não está vazia kkk

Comment: Tente assim: ORDER BY 1 ASC

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo o 1 que você diz no caso é a letra L de lote?

Comment: Não. É o numeral 1 mesmo. Quer dizer para ORDENAR pela PRIMEIRA coluna.

Comment: Não deu igual @ReginaldoRigo

Comment: Tem algum outro modo de usar a mesma Função do Distinct sem ser por ele?

Comment: Não que eu saiba. Eu testei aqui no H2, com uma tabela com estrutura parecida com a sua e funcionou, tanto com o seu SELECT quanto com o que eu sugeri. O problema não é o H2 e eu não consigo imaginar o que seria.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @ReginaldoRigo

Comment: Bom, como você só está buscando uma coluna, a query `select lote from LotesEncerrados group by lote order by lote;` deveria ter o mesmo efeito que um `select distinct`...